# tor via python - connection ok, but no showing up as on tor

Tags: python, tor

i am using the stem example of connection to the tor network, this should connect a client to the tor network, it seems to be doing this but when i check the ip address it is incorrect and not of a tor ip, any ideas as to why this and more importantly how can i fix this issue :)

```
import StringIO
import socket
import urllib

import socks  # SocksiPy module
import stem.process

from stem.util import term

SOCKS_PORT = 7000

# Set socks proxy and wrap the urllib module

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo


def query(url):
  """
  Uses urllib to fetch a site using SocksiPy for Tor over the SOCKS_PORT.
  """

  try:
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  except:
    return "Unable to reach %s" % url


# Start an instance of Tor configured to only exit through Russia. This prints
# Tor's bootstrap information as it starts. Note that this likely will not
# work if you have another Tor instance running.

def print_bootstrap_lines(line):
  if "Bootstrapped " in line:
    print term.format(line, term.Color.BLUE)


print term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD)

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
  config = {
    'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
    'ExitNodes': '{ru}',
  },
  init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

I get the output :

```
richard@Tornado:~/Documents/Masters Project$ python russiaExample.py 
Starting Tor:

May 26 21:56:49.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network.
May 26 21:56:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop.
May 26 21:56:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit.
May 26 21:56:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.
```

however when i visit https://check.torproject.org/ to check i am using tor, it says i am now, and my normal ip is shown,

what is causing this issue, as the output shown above seems to suggest it has established a circuit all ok to Tor, but seems as although it is not using it ?

i am on the right lines here ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up your browser to use **Tor** as a proxy.

If you are using **Firefox**:

1. Go to **Edit**, **preference**, **advanced** and choose  "configure how firefox connects to the internet" **settings**.
2. In  **socks host** enter `127.0.0.1` and under **port** enter **7000**.

Go to [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com) and you will see a new ip.
Or [check tor,project](https://check.torproject.org/) to see you are using **Tor** successfully.